# SharePoint 2010 _vti_bin/Webs.asmx?op=GetAllSubWebCollection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, web-services

I'm trying to use the following web service in SharePoint 2010 to list all of the sub site collections

http://sharepointsite2010/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx?op=GetAllSubWebCollection

```
string soapmessage = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                          "<soap:Body>" +
                          "<GetAllSubWebCollection xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\" />" +
                          "</soap:Body>" +
                          "</soap:Envelope>";
```

My understanding is it should return all the sub sites. In this case an additional 3 sites.

Am I missing something or using the incorrect service?

At the moment it is just bringing back the details for the root site. http://sharepointsite2010

and not bringing back details about sub collections

- http://sharepointsite2010/sites/test1
- http://sharepointsite2010/sites/test2
- http://sharepointsite2010/sites/test3

Comment: what is happening in your case ? is it not returning anything giving any error ? please provide some details.

Comment: @Siddharth Vaghasia updated question